# Is there a way to see a mesh through another mesh without it being transparent?

Tags: mesh

I don't mean like glass either just as simple as it sounds a mesh through a mesh basically ignoring physics.

Comment: I mean... what? Can you describe it more? What mesh? Through what? Under viewport? Render? Is it a portal?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender SE. Please, add some images of what you're trying to achieve. Seeing a thing through another one is a definition of transparency, physics or not :).

Comment: Do you want this in viewport or on render?

Comment: If it's not transparent, how are you supposed to see the other object?